# Search through an array for a certain String

Tags: java, arrays, search, boolean, return

In the verifyPlate method, how do I search through the array Plates for a certain string which is "platenum", then return a boolean value to the main method?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.*;

public static boolean verifyPlate(String[] plates, int numCars, Scanner keyboard)
  {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter your plate number: ");
    String platenum = s.nextLine();

    boolean real=false;

    for (int i=0;i!=plates.length;i++)
    {
       boolean platers = platenum.equals(plates[i]); 

       if(platers)
       {
           System.out.println("Your vehicle is registered");
        }
       else
        System.out.println("Your vehicle is not registered");

     platers=real;
    }

    return real;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You only need 1 line:

```
return Arrays.asList(plates).contains(platenum);
```

If plates was a list instead of an array, the call to asList could be omitted. In general, arrays are to be avoided

Answer (score 0):

Your approach won't work, since the `real` variable could be reset, after the next iteration in the loop. Try this instead:

```
public static boolean verifyPlate(String [] plates, int numCars,
                                                  Scanner keyboard) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter your plate number: ");
    String platenum = s.nextLine();

    for (int i=0;i!=plates.length;i++){
        boolean platers = platenum.equals(plates[i]); 

       if(platers) {
       System.out.println("Your vehicle is registered");   
       return true;
       }

    }
    System.out.println("Your vehicle is not registered");
    return false;
}
```